# Exist a function that satisfies these conditions?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Exist a function that safisties...?

$$f(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}g(k)=n\ : g(k)\in (0,+\infty),\ g'(k)> 0, n\in \mathbb{N}$$

And this...?

$$f(x)=\int_{0}^{x}g(t)dt=x\ : g(t)\in (0,+\infty),\ g'(t)> 0, x\in \mathbb{R^+}$$

P.S.: Im not sure what tags I can put here and I hope the question is clear for everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that infinite solutions exist for both cases. Two examples:

$$g(k)=\frac{2k}{n+1}\rightarrow f(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}g(k)=n;\ g(k)\in (0,+\infty);\ g'(k)=\frac{2}{n+1}>0$$

$$g(t)=\frac{2t}{x}\rightarrow f(x)=\int_{0}^{x}g(t)dt=x;\ g(t)\in (0,+\infty);\ g'(t)=\frac{2}{x}>0$$

Sry, it seems I put some errors at writing the question that I fixed a bit late :S

The question seems too trivial more the miswriting it was catastrophic.